# Designing simple client to control and interact with daemon in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, ipc, daemon

I am trying to design a daemon which runs in the background and a CLI client which can interact with the daemon.

When the cli program is called it should send a message to the daemon. This message should trigger an event on the daemon side. The daemon should then send a response back to the CLI program which then prints that for the user to see and then exits.

I'm a bit overwhelmed with the different options of how to tackle this. I would appreciate a simple example using libraries which I can build upon.